# Apostrophe in FeignException shows like /u0027

Tags: java, json, sonarqube, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a Feign client which I use to get information from SonarQube and when I'm trying to test request with wrong component name I have an issue with displaying apostrophes as unicode (/u0027).

Here's the test code:

```
    void measuresSearchHistoryUnknownTest() {
        assertThatExceptionOfType(FeignException.NotFound.class)
                .isThrownBy(() -> sonarFeignClient.measuresSearchHistory(
                        "badProject",
                        String.join(",",
                                EnumUtils.getJsonValue(SonarMetric.BLOCKER_VIOLATIONS),
                                EnumUtils.getJsonValue(SonarMetric.CRITICAL_VIOLATIONS)
                        ),
                        1,
                        10
                )).withMessageContaining("Component key 'badProject' not found");
//                )).withMessageContaining("Component key \\u0027badProject\\u0027 not found");
    }
```

This test works only if use last line (commented line with "\u0027badProject\u0027"), but it fails if I use previous line (with common apostrophes):

```
Expecting throwable message:
  <"[404] during [GET] to [*******/sonar/api/measures/search_history?component=badProject&metrics=blocker_violations%2Ccritical_violations&p=1&ps=10] [SonarFeignClient#measuresSearchHistory(String,String,int,int)]: [{"errors":[{"msg":"Component key \u0027badProject\u0027 not found"}]}]">
to contain:
  <"Component key 'badProject' not found">
but did not.

Throwable that failed the check:

feign.FeignException$NotFound: [404] during [GET] to [*******/sonar/api/measures/search_history?component=badProject&metrics=blocker_violations%2Ccritical_violations&p=1&ps=10] [SonarFeignClient#measuresSearchHistory(String,String,int,int)]: [{"errors":[{"msg":"Component key \u0027badProject\u0027 not found"}]}]
```

If I look this link in a browser SonarQube shows me JSON with error message and common apostrophes (not unicode), so I think an issue somewhere in Feign.

I use "spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:3.0.1"

Maybe someone can help me with that? How can I prevent parsing of apostrophes to Unicode?

Comment: It is `"\u0027"` not `"/u0027"` or `"\\u0027"`.

Comment: This seems very confused. First of all, what you are calling "common apostrophes" are Unicode, every bit as much as the letter A is Unicode. Second, using `"\u0027"` in a Java String gets you the exact same thing as if you used `"'"`. Third, what is the name of the project you want to pass on the URL? `badProject`? `'badProject'`? If you want to pass apostrophes in a URL you would URL-encode them as `%27`, as in `%27badProject%27`.

Comment: Also, when you use `"\\u0027"` that just puts a backslash, a letter, and those digits into the string and there is probably nothing in the library or the web service that parses or interprets that, so it is probably just taken as a literal backslash plus some other characters.